# Error trying to plot pie chart, how to fix?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pie-chart

I was trying out plotting graphs for the first time and tried to do a bit of code where you can enter what parameter you want to graph, and then it graphs it as a pie chart. But when I tried running it, it returns a bunch of errors

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib

plot = input()
plot = str(plot)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Perimeter': [8, 16, 20],
                   'Area': [2, 16, 25]},
                  index=['Square 1', 'Square 2', 'Square 3'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y={plot}, figsize=(5, 5))
```

The errors are:

> C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\k.py:12: FutureWarning:
> Passing a set as an indexer is deprecated and will raise in a future
> version. Use a list instead.   plot = df.plot.pie(y={plot},
> figsize=(5, 5))
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\k.py", line 12, in
>
> plot = df.plot.pie(y={plot}, figsize=(5, 5))
>
> File
> "C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_core.py",
> line 1613, in pie
> return self(kind="pie", **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting_core.py",
> line 960, in **call**
> data.index.name = y
>
> File
> "C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 1751, in name
> maybe_extract_name(value, None, type(self))
>
> File
> "C:\Users\KIAN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 7421, in maybe_extract_name
> raise TypeError(f"{cls.**name**}.name must be a hashable type")
>
> TypeError: Index.name must be a hashable type

Any idea how to fix these or what is causing them?

Comment: provide a set of input you can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `plot` shouldn't be in a set, you don't even need to assign it to a `str`, `input` will be already string even if you enter numbers:

```
plot = input()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Perimeter': [8, 16, 20],
                   'Area': [2, 16, 25]},
                  index=['Square 1', 'Square 2', 'Square 3'])
plot = df.plot.pie(y=plot, figsize=(5, 5))
```

Output for `Area`:

[image]

Comment: It didn't error so it definitely worked; however, it did not output a graph, it just finished the program